# is there a way to atomically move file and directory from tempfs to ext4 partition on eMMC

Tags: linux, rename, embedded, ext4, tmpfs

We have beaglebone black based custom board with 256MB RAM and 4GB eMMC.
Board runs Linux kernel 4.9

we are running into a situation where we create a file in `tempfs` and then after validation, we have to move it to the ext4 partition of eMMC. File nothing but a `certificate`

in some situations, we have multiple certs in a directory so we have to move the whole directory from tempfs to the ext4 partition on eMMC.

So one of the problems we are worried about is `atomicity` of `mv`(move) operation.

As per `rename` system call Linux man page renaming file is an atomic operation.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html

However we are not sure if rename operation involves moving files between two filesystems, atomicity is still available or not. So question is
Is moving file from `tmpfs` to `ext4` atomic?

Obviously, one possible solution is to keep files in a different folder on the same partition (on same filesystem obviously ) and rename it using `mv`.
For directory using below approach of renaming

```
SRC_dir  --> TMP_DEST_dir
DEST_dir --> BAK_DEST_dir
TMP_DEST_dir --> DEST_dir
delete BAK_DEST_dir
```

Any suggestion for alternatives ?

**EDIT**
After i got reply i tried following test code on the board,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int retcode = 0;

    system("touch /tmp/rename_test");

    retcode = rename("/tmp/rename_test", "/home/fs_rename_test");

    if ( retcode < 0) {
        printf("errno : %d\n",errno );
        perror("Error occurred while renaming file");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which returned following output. And confirmed that rename doesn't work cross file-system.

```
errno : 18
Error occurred while renaming file: Invalid cross-device link
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is moving file from `tmpfs` to `ext4` atomic?

No. Renames as such only work within a filesystem. The manual page for `rename(2)` explicitly mentions the error that is returned if trying to rename across mount points:

> `EXDEV`  *oldpath* and *newpath* are not on the same mounted filesystem.

Moves across file systems need to be done as a combination of a copy and a delete. `mv` will do this for you if the `rename()` doesn't work, but it will not be atomic in that case.

The simple way to work around that would indeed be to first copy the file to a temporary location on the same filesystem. In general, it's simplest to place the temporary file in the same directory as the final destination, since that's the only place that's guaranteed to be on the same filesystem.
Of course that requires that any process working on the files there will have some logic to ignore the temporary based on its name.

Roughly, something like this should work for one file:

```
cp /src/filename /dst/filename.tmp &&
mv /dst/filename.tmp /dst/filename &&
rm /src/filename
```

Note that the process you describe for a *directory* is essentially this:

```
cp -r /src/dir /dst/dir.tmp && 
mv /dst/dir /dst/dir.bak    &&
mv /dst/dir.tmp /dst/dir    &&
rm -r /dst/dir.bak
```

Which is not bad, but is *not* atomic. There's a moment of time between the two runs of `mv` (or calls to `rename()`), when `/dst/dir` does not exist. That could be worked around by accessing the directory through a symlink, since the link can be atomically replaced with a rename.

Comment: `tmpfs` as such is in the ram and there is no device for it as such. And I am able to move the file so it works right?

Comment: @AnkurTank, the fact that it's `tmpfs` doesn't matter, it's still a filesystem like any other. `mv` will copy the file data for you if the rename doesn't work, but that's not atomic: there will be a split second when the file exists with zero length, and if it's larger than what `mv` writes in one system call, some other process may also see the file when it's half-written.

Comment: you are right. `mv` does the trick. I checked `mv.c` of busybox and found that it checks for errno set by rename system call , if errno `EXDEV` then it calls `copy_file` and `remove_file`.