# Is mv atomic operation between two file systems?

Tags: rename, mv

Is moving a file via the `mv` command between two filesystems an atomic operation?

Comment: My impression or is it the 2nd time you are asking this here in the last few days?

Comment: This is my first question here.

Comment: Can someone tell me why the question is getting down votes? I feel the question is simple ,yet meaningful and complete.

Comment: FWIW, there was another take on this subject just a few days prior to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452084/170373 . Might explain some of the downvotes, then again, it might just be that the downvoters take this as "plain obvious". Hard to say.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the EXDEV error (in man 2 rename):

> ```
>    EXDEV  oldpath and newpath are not  on  the  same  mounted  filesystem.
>           (Linux  permits  a  filesystem to be mounted at multiple points,
>           but rename() does not work across different mount  points,  even
>           if the same filesystem is mounted on both.)
> ```

You can't move between file-systems with a system call, so what mv does is a user-space copy and delete, which is never atomic.

Comment: Note that that documentation is Linux-specific; POSIX [allows this error](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) but implementations are allowed to diverge.

Comment: You are not correct, it could be implemented in a way that would make it behave as if it was atomically. It just isn't since the `mv(1)` program does not implement it's copy routine the right way.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt: Correct, ZFS permits a `rename(2)` between different filesystems in case they are on the same `ZPOOL`.

Comment: @ schily You can always interrupt the process between the system calls. How would your method do the atomic move?

Comment: @ctrl-d: a sycall may be interrupted by a power outage. So you always need just a method that is transaction based and allows a rollback.

Comment: You can never have a file disappear in one place and appear in another place without there being time in-between which can be intruded by other processes. Only the kernel can keep other processes out of that time period. So only system calls can do such a thing.

Comment: You are wrong again even though you have been given an explanation that there is no difference between kernel and userland.

Comment: Please provide an atomic move function in C then

Answer (score -2):

This depends on what you understand by "atomically".

Unlike the `rename()` syscall, copying files bewteen two filesystems is usually not atomically. Since the copy routine in `mv` does not call `fsync(2)`, there may be late filesystem errors that are not detected.

Comment: It's _never_ atomic across filesystems.

Comment: As mentioned, you are mistaken since it is possible to implement things in a way that makes it look like it was atomic and behave as if it was atomic.

Comment: I would consider the term "atomically" that there's no in-between state possible in the process of moving.

Comment: Can you find me a reference for the ZFS rename(2) implementation please? I've looked but can only find it recorded as a wish-list item against the filesystem. (Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places...)

Comment: It was mentioned either in mails on the OpenSolaris mailing lists or has been part of a talk on a Opensolaris core developers meeting in Sante Cruz.

Comment: atomic rename has nothing to do with durability (fsync)